# NetworkInfo Native Extension for AIR

Tags: ios, air, adobe, air-native-extension

I need to know/handle when my Adobe AIR iOS app has lost wifi or 3G connection so thought I'd use the NetworkInfo class to do this (as per the info on this page
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/networkinfo.html )

Anybody can help me figure out why I'm having the error below?

```
ArgumentError: Error #3500: The extension context does not have a method with the name getInterfaces.
          at flash.external::ExtensionContext/call()
          at com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Networkinfo::NetworkInfo/findInterfaces()[ /Users/gangwar/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/NetworkInfoActionScriptLibrary/src/com/adobe/nativeExtensions/Net workinfo/NetworkInfo.as:70]
          at com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Networkinfo::NetworkInfo/findInterfaces()
```

Or, is there perhaps a better solution out there to figure out whether the device has lost connection to wifi or 3G?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution to this error has been to hide the ANE symbols:

[image]

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. forgot to get back to this question on SO, in the end I was able to successfully use the NetworkInfo ANE. I believe that error was pointing to a conflict with another one of my ANEs.